# CounterUp2 - No puedo animar todos los números

Tags: javascript, jquery, animación, libreria

estoy usando el plugin CounterUp2 para animar unos numeros cuando se haga scroll. El problema es que solo se anima el primero de ellos a pesar de tener todos la misma clase. No encuentro mucha información al respecto. He seguido la página oficial de github y un codepen que he encontrado. Con la versión anterior del plugin consigo animar todos a la vez, pero cuando hago scroll de nuevo los números finales no son correctos, algo bastante extraño lo cual hace que tampoco me valga esa versión. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Saludos,

Pedro

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

const counterUp = window.counterUp.default

const callback = entries => {
    entries.forEach( entry => {
        const el = entry.target
        if ( entry.isIntersecting && ! el.classList.contains( 'is-visible' ) ) {
            counterUp( el, {
                duration: 2000,
                delay: 16,
            } )
            el.classList.add( 'is-visible' )
        }
    } )
}

const IO = new IntersectionObserver( callback, { threshold: 1 } )

const el = document.querySelector( '.counter' )
IO.observe( el )


});
```

```css
/* estilos generales */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #002456;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

/* estilos index */

#separador{
  height: 150vh;
}


.contador {
  width: 80%;
  height: 33vh;
  background-color: #002456;
  margin: 8.3vh auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.contador>div {
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.numero, .unidad {
  color: white;
}

.numero {
  font-size: 42pt;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.unidad {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contador</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/mht7chq.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/counterup2@2.0.2/dist/index.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <section id="separador">
      <h1>Haz scroll</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="contador">

      <div>
        <h3 class="numero counter">50</h3>
        <h4 class="unidad">PROYECTOS</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3 class="numero counter">500</h3>
        <h4 class="unidad">PROYECTOS</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3 class="numero counter">5000</h3>
        <h4 class="unidad">PROYECTOS</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3 class="numero counter">8000</h3>
        <h4 class="unidad">PROYECTOS</h4>
      </div>

    </section>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cosas que pasan al usar librerias de terceros

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas consultando solo un elemento, debes consultar todos usando `querySelectorAll` y asignando el observer a cada uno.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

const counterUp = window.counterUp.default

const callback = entries => {
    entries.forEach( entry => {
        const el = entry.target
        if ( entry.isIntersecting && ! el.classList.contains( 'is-visible' ) ) {
            counterUp( el, {
                duration: 2000,
                delay: 16,
            } )
            el.classList.add( 'is-visible' )
        }
    } )
}

const IO = new IntersectionObserver( callback, { threshold: 1 } ) 

const els = document.querySelectorAll( '.counter' ) //Cambio

els.forEach(el => IO.observe( el )) //Cambio


});
```

```css
/* estilos generales */
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  font-family: itc-avant-garde-gothic-pro, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #002456;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
}

/* estilos index */

#separador{
  height: 150vh;
}


.contador {
  width: 80%;
  height: 33vh;
  background-color: #002456;
  margin: 8.3vh auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.contador>div {
  width: 25%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.numero, .unidad {
  color: white;
}

.numero {
  font-size: 42pt;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.unidad {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Contador</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/mht7chq.css">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/counterup2@2.0.2/dist/index.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>


</head>

<body>

    <section id="separador">
      <h1>Haz scroll</h1>
    </section>

    <section class="contador">

      <div>
        <h3 class="numero counter">50</h3>
        <h4 class="unidad">PROYECTOS</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3 class="numero counter">500</h3>
        <h4 class="unidad">PROYECTOS</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3 class="numero counter">5000</h3>
        <h4 class="unidad">PROYECTOS</h4>
      </div>

      <div>
        <h3 class="numero counter">8000</h3>
        <h4 class="unidad">PROYECTOS</h4>
      </div>

    </section>

</body>

</html>
```